# How can I create an Amazon S3 clone on my host?

Tags: php, rest, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am currently building a storage service, but I am very small and don't want to setup or pay for an Amazon S3 account. I already have my own hosting service which I want to use. However, I want to make it simple to switch to Amazon S3 if the need arises. Therefore, I would like to have essentially an S3 'clone' on my server, which I can simply redirect to amazons servers at a later time. Is there any package that can do this?

EDIT: I am on a shared server where I cannot install software, so is there a simple php page that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nimbus](http://www.nimbusproject.org/) allows for that. From FAQ:

> Cumulus is an open source implementation of the S3 REST API. Some
>   features such as versioning and COPY are not yet implemented, but some
>   additional features are added, such as file system usage quotas.

http://www.nimbusproject.org/doc/nimbus/faq/#what-is-cumulus

Comment: Wow, yes, that certainly does what I asked. So, I should be more specific. That is wayyy overkill, so much so in fact that I cant use it. I was hoping for a php page that emulates the interface. Reason is that im on a shared server where I cant install software. Any other reccomendations?

Comment: @chacham15 Does your hosting service provide cloud storage service? If not, you will end up having to setup your own storage server. It's not that hard to setup though.

Comment: @chacham15 BTW, I don't think an 'S3 Clone' is a simple php page. Its a infrastructure you have to setup on your server. Either through cloud hosting services or your own server. If you have a PC large enough to be a server, you can install XenServer and install one instance of LAMP server there for your PHP site, and then setup a storage server on it too. For testing this should be enough.

Comment: it doesnt supply cloud storage persay, but it does allow me to store files. That is what I mean, I dont want a cloud solution, only a php page that imitates a cloud solution but behind the scenes is just reading/writing to the local drive.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud

you would need several host computers but it works well.

I too have a backup service, but it's based on several 48TB raid arrays.